# JavaScript design pattern or node packages for nesting of de-normalized/flattened database query results

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, multidimensional-array, data-structures

I'm a bit new to NodeJS and using Javascripts for these types of problems, so am feeling a bit stuck here. I'm working with a traditional relational database backend (Postgres) that has a fairly typical hierarchical (i.e. normalized) table/entity structure. One of my requirements for my NodeJs application is to pull data for a page (HTML report) that essentially incorporates all tables, but the page needs to show the data very hierarchically as well. Imagine a query result like this:

```
[
{"CompanyId":1,"CompanyType":"Technology","CompanyEmployess":3000,"DepartmentId":12,"DepartmentName":"Analytics", "DepartmentEmployees":50, "EmployeeId":1234,"EmployeeName":"Fred","EmployeeHireDate":"2012-09-05"},
{"CompanyId":1,"CompanyType":"Technology","CompanyEmployess":3000,"DepartmentId":12,"DepartmentName":"Analytics", "DepartmentEmployees":50, "EmployeeId":145,"EmployeeName":"Joana","EmployeeHireDate":"2019-09-01"},
{"CompanyId":1,"CompanyType":"Technology","CompanyEmployess":3000,"DepartmentId":8,"DepartmentName":"Accounting", "DepartmentEmployees":25, "EmployeeId":1752,"EmployeeName":"Mary","EmployeeHireDate":"2020-08-01"},
{"CompanyId":1,"CompanyType":"Technology","CompanyEmployess":3000,"DepartmentId":8,"DepartmentName":"Accounting", "DepartmentEmployees":25, "EmployeeId":658,"EmployeeName":"Jose","EmployeeHireDate":"2018-12-01"},
{"CompanyId":1,"CompanyType":"Technology","CompanyEmployess":3000,"DepartmentId":1,"DepartmentName":"Executive", "DepartmentEmployees":4, "EmployeeId":9,"EmployeeName":"Maurice","EmployeeHireDate":"2011-10-01"}
]
```

But, the best structure for display purposes (in the reporting tools like jsreport) would be more representative of the actual hierarchy, so I can loop through and make nested `<tables>` and/or `<divs>`. Like this:

```
[
  {
    "CompanyId": 1,
    "CompanyType": "Technology",
    "CompanyEmployees": 3000,
    "Departments": [
      {
        "DepartmentId": 12,
        "DepartmentName": "Analytics",
        "DepartmentEmployees": 50,
        "Employees": [
          {
            "EmployeeId": 1234,
            "EmployeeName": "Fred",
            "EmployeeHireDate": "2012-09-05"
          },
          {
            "EmployeeId": 145,
            "EmployeeName": "Joana",
            "EmployeeHireDate": "2019-09-01"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "DepartmentId": 8,
        "DepartmentName": "Accounting",
        "DepartmentEmployees": 25,
        "Employees": [
          {
            "EmployeeId": 1752,
            "EmployeeName": "Mary",
            "EmployeeHireDate": "2020-08-01"
          },
          {
            "EmployeeId": 658,
            "EmployeeName": "Jose",
            "EmployeeHireDate": "2018-12-01"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "DepartmentId": 1,
        "DepartmentName": "Executive",
        "DepartmentEmployees": 4,
        "Employees": [
          {
            "EmployeeId": 9,
            "EmployeeName": "Maurice",
            "EmployeeHireDate": "2011-10-01"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I would like to, keep pulling data in a single query call as shown and doing something like `array.reduce()` or package like 'normalizr' to re-structure the data. I'm open to ideas though.

Where I'm getting lost in the `array.reduce()` logic is pulling multiple elements that represent a parent object/entity up to the higher level. I would think it would be a common problem, but I can't seem to find examples of people using `array.reduce()` to do this particular use case.

Comment: i don't think there is a special package that does exactly what you want to do, maybe something like sequelize orm in nodejs , but to massage your data, you don't have to make it async, it can be done in a synchronous loop. If what you are using async for performing one query after another using data from previous result , you can always use the new async await syntax to write it like synchronous code and then convert it to the javascript version you want using babel if the nodejs interpreter is your limitation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an approach:

```js
const array = [
    {
        "CompanyId": 1,
        "CompanyType": "Technology",
        "CompanyEmployess": 3000,
        "DepartmentId": 12,
        "DepartmentName": "Analytics",
        "DepartmentEmployees": 50,
        "EmployeeId": 1234,
        "EmployeeName": "Fred",
        "EmployeeHireDate": "2012-09-05"
    },
    {
        "CompanyId": 1,
        "CompanyType": "Technology",
        "CompanyEmployess": 3000,
        "DepartmentId": 12,
        "DepartmentName": "Analytics",
        "DepartmentEmployees": 50,
        "EmployeeId": 145,
        "EmployeeName": "Joana",
        "EmployeeHireDate": "2019-09-01"
    },
    {
        "CompanyId": 1,
        "CompanyType": "Technology",
        "CompanyEmployess": 3000,
        "DepartmentId": 8,
        "DepartmentName": "Accounting",
        "DepartmentEmployees": 25,
        "EmployeeId": 1752,
        "EmployeeName": "Mary",
        "EmployeeHireDate": "2020-08-01"
    },
    {
        "CompanyId": 1,
        "CompanyType": "Technology",
        "CompanyEmployess": 3000,
        "DepartmentId": 8,
        "DepartmentName": "Accounting",
        "DepartmentEmployees": 25,
        "EmployeeId": 658,
        "EmployeeName": "Jose",
        "EmployeeHireDate": "2018-12-01"
    },
    {
        "CompanyId": 1,
        "CompanyType": "Technology",
        "CompanyEmployess": 3000,
        "DepartmentId": 1,
        "DepartmentName": "Executive",
        "DepartmentEmployees": 4,
        "EmployeeId": 9,
        "EmployeeName": "Maurice",
        "EmployeeHireDate": "2011-10-01"
    }
];

const result = array.reduce((prev, curr) => {
    const company_found = prev.find(x => x.CompanyId === curr.CompanyId);
    if (!company_found) {
        prev.push({
            CompanyId: curr.CompanyId,
            CompanyType: curr.CompanyType,
            CompanyEmployees: curr.CompanyEmployees,
            Departments: [
                {
                    DepartmentId: curr.DepartmentId,
                    DepartmentName: curr.DepartmentName,
                    DepartmentEmployees: curr.DepartmentEmployees,
                    Employees: [
                        {
                            EmployeeId: curr.EmployeeId,
                            EmployeeName: curr.EmployeeName,
                            EmployeeHireDate: curr.EmployeeHireDate
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        })
    }
    else {
        let department_found = company_found.Departments.find(x => x.DepartmentId === curr.DepartmentId);
        if (department_found) {
            department_found.Employees.push({
                EmployeeId: curr.EmployeeId,
                EmployeeName: curr.EmployeeName,
                EmployeeHireDate: curr.EmployeeHireDate
            });
        }
        else{
            company_found.Departments.push({
                DepartmentId: curr.DepartmentId,
                DepartmentName: curr.DepartmentName,
                DepartmentEmployees: curr.DepartmentEmployees,
                Employees: [
                    {
                        EmployeeId: curr.EmployeeId,
                        EmployeeName: curr.EmployeeName,
                        EmployeeHireDate: curr.EmployeeHireDate
                    }
                ]
            })
        }
    }

    return prev;
}, []);

console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 4));
```

````
const array = [
    {
        "CompanyId": 1,
        "CompanyType": "Technology",
        "CompanyEmployess": 3000,
        "DepartmentId": 12,
        "DepartmentName": "Analytics",
        "DepartmentEmployees": 50,
        "EmployeeId": 1234,
        "EmployeeName": "Fred",
        "EmployeeHireDate": "2012-09-05"
    },
    {
        "CompanyId": 1,
        "CompanyType": "Technology",
        "CompanyEmployess": 3000,
        "DepartmentId": 12,
        "DepartmentName": "Analytics",
        "DepartmentEmployees": 50,
        "EmployeeId": 145,
        "EmployeeName": "Joana",
        "EmployeeHireDate": "2019-09-01"
    },
    {
        "CompanyId": 1,
        "CompanyType": "Technology",
        "CompanyEmployess": 3000,
        "DepartmentId": 8,
        "DepartmentName": "Accounting",
        "DepartmentEmployees": 25,
        "EmployeeId": 1752,
        "EmployeeName": "Mary",
        "EmployeeHireDate": "2020-08-01"
    },
    {
        "CompanyId": 1,
        "CompanyType": "Technology",
        "CompanyEmployess": 3000,
        "DepartmentId": 8,
        "DepartmentName": "Accounting",
        "DepartmentEmployees": 25,
        "EmployeeId": 658,
        "EmployeeName": "Jose",
        "EmployeeHireDate": "2018-12-01"
    },
    {
        "CompanyId": 1,
        "CompanyType": "Technology",
        "CompanyEmployess": 3000,
        "DepartmentId": 1,
        "DepartmentName": "Executive",
        "DepartmentEmployees": 4,
        "EmployeeId": 9,
        "EmployeeName": "Maurice",
        "EmployeeHireDate": "2011-10-01"
    }
];

const result = array.reduce((prev, curr) => {
    const company_found = prev.find(x => x.CompanyId === curr.CompanyId);
    if (!company_found) {
        prev.push({
            CompanyId: curr.CompanyId,
            CompanyType: curr.CompanyType,
            CompanyEmployees: curr.CompanyEmployees,
            Departments: [
                {
                    DepartmentId: curr.DepartmentId,
                    DepartmentName: curr.DepartmentName,
                    DepartmentEmployees: curr.DepartmentEmployees,
                    Employees: [
                        {
                            EmployeeId: curr.EmployeeId,
                            EmployeeName: curr.EmployeeName,
                            EmployeeHireDate: curr.EmployeeHireDate
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        })
    }
    else {
        let department_found = company_found.Departments.find(x => x.DepartmentId === curr.DepartmentId);
        if (department_found) {
            department_found.Employees.push({
                EmployeeId: curr.EmployeeId,
                EmployeeName: curr.EmployeeName,
                EmployeeHireDate: curr.EmployeeHireDate
            });
        }
        else{
            company_found.Departments.push({
                DepartmentId: curr.DepartmentId,
                DepartmentName: curr.DepartmentName,
                DepartmentEmployees: curr.DepartmentEmployees,
                Employees: [
                    {
                        EmployeeId: curr.EmployeeId,
                        EmployeeName: curr.EmployeeName,
                        EmployeeHireDate: curr.EmployeeHireDate
                    }
                ]
            })
        }
    }

    return prev;
}, []);

console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 4));```
````